# How to prevent users to see other users entry in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, item-level-permissions

We have created an SharePoint list, Where user has to raise a request for any facility related issue. So my concern is that, Everything is setup.

But Everybody is able to see others request as well in the list & which shouldn't be.

Can any body help me. So only admin or selected user group can see the all items in list.

Quick reference is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using SharePoint OOTB functionality we can show only the items relevant to the current logged in user, to do so, goto the list settings --> view settings --> filter --> select the column name equals to [ME].

After applying this, the items relevant to the current logged in user will only be displayed in the list view.

for more information, step by step guide, refer below url,

https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/sharepoint-library-views-and-list-views/

Comment: Thank you Karthhik.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for **Item-level Permissions** in SharePoint.

You can set the item level permissions on your list like below:

[image]

You can read more about it and learn how to enable it step by step from below article:

[How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/).